# How to return an array from a Restful Web service?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, debugging, jax-rs

I have the following web service in which I want to return and values of array

```
@GET
@Consumes("text/plain")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String[] getText(@PathParam("name") String Uname) {
    //TODO return proper representation object
    System.out.println("In Method " + Uname);
    String arr[]=null;
     arr=new String[2];
    arr[0]="demo";
    arr[1]="demo2";
    return arr;
}
```

But when I test this web services it is giving me this error: `GET RequestFailed RequestFailed --> Status: (406) Response: {`

So what should I do if I want to return an array from a REST webservice?

Comment: Why do you use so many question marks??????????????

Comment: Do you want to return an array represented as XML? This might help: http://java.dzone.com/articles/xml-bindings-jaxb-and-jax-rs

Comment: Not really I want to return as Plain Text I have made the change in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP responses do not support Arrays in plain text responses. You either need to manually represent your array as a String, change the return type to String and return like this:

```
return Arrays.toString(arr);
```

Or you could convert your array to a List:
    return Arrays.asList(arr);

and use the approach to return it as JSON or XML here:
[Jersey: Return a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392413/jersey-return-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: Hey, your first trick works. Could be please explain this statement with some example " encode your response as as JSON array and return that as a String " How to do this I have no idea ?

Comment: @CSSG I edited my answer to link to another post with more details. This is only useful however if you want your response as JSON or XML instead of plain text.