# Why POST endpoint not being invoked but GET endpoint is being invoked - jersey container grizzly2

Tags: kotlin, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

I can't figure out why my GET endpoint gets called but my POST endpoint is not working. When I call `curl -v -X GET http://localhost:8080/myresource/test123` it succesfully returns `hello`

But when I call

```
curl -v -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/myresource \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"test": "testvalue"}'
```

I keep getting this response:

```
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)

> POST /myresource HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 21
> 
* upload completely sent off: 21 out of 21 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Request failed.
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 1031
< 
* Closing connection 0
<html><head><title>Grizzly 2.4.0</title><style><!--div.header {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#003300;font-size:22px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;border-top-left-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;border-top-right-radius: 10px;padding-left: 5px}div.body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:#FFFFCC;font-size:16px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px}div.footer {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#666633;font-size:14px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;padding-left: 5px}BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;}A {color : black;}HR {color : #999966;}--></style> </head><body><div class="header">Request failed.</div><div class="body">Request failed.</div><div class="footer">Grizzly 2.4.0</div></body></html>%
```

Here is my code

```
import javax.ws.rs.*
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response


@Path("myresource")
class HelloWorldResource {


    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun createMessage(testPost: String): Response {
        return Response.status(200).entity("helllo post").build()
    }


    @GET
    @Path("{testGet}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun getMessage(@PathParam("testGet") testGet: String): Response {
        return Response.status(200).entity("hello").build()
    }
}
```

Comment: 5xx errors with JAX-RS represent some kind of exception being thrown.  Do you have that exception handy?

Comment: It can possible be due to `createMessage` taking `String` but your POST body contains JSON that might likely be marshalled into POJO with one `test` field.

Comment: Register [this DebugExceptionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31289875/2587435) with your application. Most likely you will see the exception that is being swallowed by the container. If after seeing the exception, you can't figure out how to fix it, post the exception/stacktrace here.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual underlying exception, it's hard to say for sure, but likely you're running into similar issues as [Jersey: Return a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392413/jersey-return-a-list-of-strings) with mismatches between a `String` type and a `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` produces/consumes declarations.  If you're dealing in raw strings, I'd suggest using MediaType.PLAIN_TEXT, or having your post body and return value be an entity that can be represented as a non-raw-string json object (ie, something enclosed in `{}`), and making sure a jackson provider is registered with jersey.